# How the actual image size work on flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

In the following image my phone screen size is (1080x1920) and the image (a red square) showing on the screen is (400x400) pixels. But the image occupy large space more than 400px on the device screen. Why flutter show in such way? Doesn't flutter care about actual image pixel?

As far as I know, in normal (Java) android app it take place only the image size (if image size is 72 then showing 72x72 pixels) on the screen, if we need large image for high-res screens, it needs to create the same image with larger size.

[image]

Following is the dart code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Image align test',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Image align test'),
        ),
        body: Container(child: Image.asset('images/pic1.png')),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try wrapping the Image into a `Center`

Answer (score 1):

How the image is sized is determined by the BoxFit. The Widget itself takes as much space as possible. You can supply that to the image (e.g. `Image.asset('images/pic1.png',fit: BoxFit.cover)`. The whole enum is found [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html), but the one you expect is probably Boxfit.none:

[image: Boxfit.none]